# Rendering a top menu bar conflicts with creation of dataTable

Tags: javascript, php, html, datatables

I'm currently working on a project where I have to design a small website. I would like all pages to have a top menu with which the user can navigate between the pages of the website. I have made the following php function for that purpose

```
<?php
function renderMenuToHTML($currentPageId) {
        // idPage titre
    $mymenu = array('profile','page_aliments');
    echo "<nav class=menu id=barre_top>";
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($mymenu as $pageId) {
        if($currentPageId==$pageId) {
            echo '<li><a id=currentpage href="'._prefix.$pageId.'">'.$pageId.'</a></li>';
        }
        else {
            echo '<li><a href="'._prefix.$pageId.'">'.$pageId.'</a></li>';
        }
    }
    //echo "<li><img src=en_flag.png href='http://localhost/IDAW/SitePro/v3/'.$chgt.'/index.php?lang='.$chgt.'&page='.$currentPageId></li>"
    echo "</ul>";
    echo "</nav";
}
```

I then call this function in my other pages for the menu to be created in each of them:

```
<?php require_once('header.html');
    require_once("template_menu.php");
    $currentPageId = 'page_aliments';
    //renderMenuToHTML($currentPageId);
?>

<table class="table" id="AlimentsTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Nom</th>
                <th scope="col">Energie (kcal)</th>
                <th scope="col">Lipides (g)</th>
                <th scope="col">Glucides (g)</th>
                <th scope="col">Sucres (g)</th>
                <th scope="col">Fibres (g)</th>
                <th scope="col">Proteines (g)</th>
                <th scope="col">Sel (g)</th>
                <th scope="col">Edit/delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
        </table>

<script>defTable()</script>
```

Finally, as you can see I can the defTable function which renders a dataTable with the following js code:

```
function defTable(){
    $('#AlimentsTable').DataTable({
        ajax: {
        url: prefix+'aliments.php', 
        dataSrc: ''
        },
        responsive: true,
        columns: [
            {data:'NOM_ALIMENT'},
            {data:'ENERGIE'},
            {data:'LIPIDES'},
            {data:'GLUCIDES'},
            {data:'SUCRE'},
            {data:'FIBRES'},
            {data:'PROTEINES'},
            {data:'SEL'},
            {
            data: null,
            render: function(data, type, row) {
                return '<button onclick="editData(' + data.id + ')">Edit</button>' +
                       '<button id=delRow onclick="delAjax(' + data.id + ');delRow(this)">Delete</button>';
            }
            }   
        ]
    });
}
```

My problem is that when I try to call both the renderMenuToHTML() and defTable() functions they seem to conflict with each other and the dataTable doesn't load properly. If I call either of the functions without the other they work fine. Could somebody help me fix this?

Comment: _"and the dataTable doesn't load properly"_ - so it loads ... "improperly" (if so, what would that actually mean then?), or not at all? Any errors in the browser console?